# How can I change the Azure Functions backend for an endpoint/operation in Azure API Management service?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

I am developing a new version of an Azure Functions app that we have been using for several years. The app has gone through a number of versions. For each major version, following the recommendations, I have created a new Function App. In the last version I used the Proxy capability in Azure Functions to redirect calls from the old version to the new version on a function by function basis so that I could roll out the new version in a controlled fashion. Proxies are technically still an option but they are not available in Azure Functions v4 and the use of API Management is suggested.

I have look into API Management and it looks like a better solution moving forward except I can't find out how to change the Azure Function backend for a particular API end-point/operation. I created a new API based on my older Azure Functions app and API Management correctly generated all the end-point/operation. I was hoping that I could just go into each end-point/operation and change the backend but what I find is the Azure Resource value is read-only.

[image]

Is there a way to assign a different Azure Resource (Azure Function app) to an end-point/operation?

Is my problem that I let API management automatically generate the API and so it is locked in to the Azure Functions app that generated it?

What would be the recommended way to have one API where I can change the backend as needed per end-point/operation?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found what I was looking for.

In the "Inbound processing" section of the design of an endpoint/operation there was a "set-backend-service" policy that allowed me to change the backend service. This will do the trick for me I think.

[image]